# Month End Tracker

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a spreadsheet with the following values:

```
       A                    B                C             D            E

Active Clients     Cost Per Client         Total         Month         Value
       5                 £100           =Sum(A3*B3)       Nov
                                                          Dec
                                                          Jan
```

The active clients are linked to another spreadsheet, so this value could potentially change each month.

What I need is that at the end of each month e.g. Nov the Total in C is transfered and locked in Column E. So Nov, Dec , Jan might have different Values. I understand I could just copy and paste it at as vaules at the end of each month, but I'm not going to be using it, and the person who is want's it done automatically.

I'm guessing it'll need VBA but I know nothing about it.

Any Help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Paul, the one important thing that's not clear from your question is how this spreadsheet is used, which would help how determine in what way the sheet could be/should be automated for this task. For example: is the sheet opened at random times by random users? is it used for a specific job every day? is it called by some batch process?

Comment: It's going to be opened up by the company director to monitor monthly profiles. Once it's completed I'll probably never see it again as the information is not for my eyes, so they want to be able to open it up randomly and the information be correct.

Comment: From my POV, the tricky thing is: if it's not opened at the end of the month, then the monthly calculation will not be missed (opening several days late means the number of clients could be different and thus give you an incorrect calculation. You can always make a button to copy it. Would they be happy with that? Alternative: it copies automatically EVERY DAY but the target cell advances on every month. So if you open on Dec 30,31, it copies to the Dec row; open on Jan 1,2 it copies to the Jan row. (they would have to save it to make sure the update is saved)

Comment: I see what you mean - didn't think about that. Ok Thanks. i think I'm going to have to go back to the drawing board with them to sort out what they want

Comment: The formula in C3 is already wrong. It should be =A3*B3.  The SUM has not effect there.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to learn Excel VBA is to record an Excel macro and then examine the code it generates (NOTE: I'm not sure if this works in Excel 2007, but it definately works in 2003 and XP).

- Figure out exactly what you want to do and write down the steps (e.g. Select values, Edit-Copy, Click on Destination Sheet, Click in correct area, Edit-Paste Values).
- Then go to Tools > Macro > Record New Macro (Excel 2002/XP)
- After doing all the actions you want to do, stop the macro.
- Then go to Tools > Macro > Visual Basic Editor
- On the left side of the Visual Basic Editor, find "Module1" in the Modules folder.
- You'll see the code for your macro in there.

Perhaps there are other things you may need to learn to polish the VBA code in that macro.  For example, if the number of items you need to select changes, you'll need to write code for that.  Another example: if you want to bind the macro to when the user clicks a button, you'll need to write code for that.

Try recording the macro, then let us know exactly where you need help in VBA, and we can try to help you figure out the rest of your code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi I've created a basic macro. To copy and paste the info and can understand what it means.

Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+k
'
    
    Range("E3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("I3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub

This is where I fall down. I need it to check what the TODAY() date is and at the 1st of each month. Copy Cell E3 and then paste it into the values cell next to the relevant month.

Cheers

Comment: Two Things: 1) Can you edit your post above and copy the code from the macro into your post? That will make it more readable. 2) What do you think of allowing the user to click a button that will copy the values and "lock" the data into the other column.  I can show you how to check the day, but the problem is, if the user doesn't open it on the first of the month (like Nov 1 being a Sunday), the code won't work the way you expect.  Let me know what you think.